# QTableView - checkbox is never checked

Tags: python, qt

I have a `QTableView` object with custom model - for which I'd like to have first column of each row with checkbox. Following several Google/SO searches, I found a way that let's me show the checkbox, but the problem is that checkbox never becomes checked in the UI, even if I force state to checked from the model.

Table init

```py
self.tableview_triggers = self.findChildren(QTableView, "tableview_triggers")[0]
self.datamodel_triggers = TableView_DataModel_Triggers()
self.tableview_triggers.setModel(self.datamodel_triggers)
```

My model (it extends `QAbstractTableModel`)

```
class TableView_DataModel_Triggers(TableView_DataModel):
    _columnNames = ['Id', 'Type', 'Enabled', 'Importance', 'Label']

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TableView_DataModel_Triggers, self).__init__(parent)
        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            c = index.column()
            cname = ''
            if c < len(self._columnNames):
                cname = self._columnNames[c]
            else:
                return ''

            if cname == 'Id':
                return item.id
            elif cname == 'Type':
                return item.type
            elif cname == 'Enabled':
                return 'Yes' if item.enabled == 1 else 'No'
            elif cname == 'Label':
                return item.label
            elif cname == 'Importance':
                return item.importance
            else:
                return cname
        elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            print("Item checked:", item.checked)

            # We force the role
            return Qt.Checked # Force checked state
            return Qt.Checked if item.checked else Qt.Unchecked
        return None

    # Set data to apply new state
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            # Set checked state to internal object
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.checked = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    # Apply flags
    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        return fl
```

As per docs, I have:

- Implemented `setData` function, that gets well called with correct index and role to `CheckStateRole`
- Implemented `data` function with `CheckStateRole`, **that forces to return `Qt.Checked`** (to make sure it returns correct value)
- Flags function that make it editable and user selectable. Yet clicking on the checkbox does nothing, and checkbox is unchecked on loading.

I also have a row double click event on table - removing it does not help.

[image: GUI snapshot with checked state reported in setData function]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself - there is a big in PySide `6.4.0` and is solved with fix for `6.4.0.1`

More here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/140632/qtableview-checkbox-is-never-checked

Bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1930